# Query only ever returns the current month

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server and I would like to have a table for the current year where all months for this year are displayed, even if the value is 0.

The result is shown to me:

```
     Month  Summe    maschnr   
    -------------------------
     1      300         23
```

Here is my example for this year what I want:

```
     Month  Summe   maschnr.   
    ------------------------
     1      300       23
     2      0         23
     3      0         23
     4      0         23 
     5      0         23 
     6      0         23
     7      0         23
     8      0         23 
     9      0         23
     10     0         23
     11     0         23
     12     0         23
```

Can you help me?

My query is

```
SELECT 
    masch_nr, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), SUM(gut_pri) / 1000) AS summe, 
    MONTH(begin_ts) AS Monat
FROM 
    [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll]
WHERE 
    masch_nr = 'FIMI3'
    AND satz_art = 'T'
    AND YEAR(begin_ts) = '2021'
GROUP BY 
    masch_nr, MONTH(begin_ts)
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have any rows in the table for those months?

Comment: What you show as results couldn't be the output of the query you have issues with. Also, are masch_nr  and maschnr different columns?

Comment: (P.S. the query will probably give you two months in February, not just "the current month" - you're confusing one row and the fact that there has only been one month so far this year.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in the gaps for data that doesn't exist. What row in your table could possibly output February?

```
DECLARE @year int = 2021;

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT m FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) AS m(m)
),
m(m) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (12) DATEFROMPARTS(@year, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n.m), 1) 
  FROM n CROSS JOIN n AS n2
)
SELECT [Month] = MONTH(m.m), 
  CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(ap.gut_pri)/1000) AS summe, 
  ap.masch_nr
FROM m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN hydra1.hydadm.v_ade_protokoll AS ap
  ON  ap.begin_ts >= m.m 
  AND ap.begin_ts < DATEADD(MONTH,1,m.m)
  AND ap.masch_nr = 'FIMI3' 
  AND ap satz_art = 'T'
GROUP BY m.m, 
  ap.masch_nr -- do you really need this? There can only be one
ORDER BY m.m;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table doesn't contain rows for the following months, you need to introduce some values in your query.
Maybe something like this:

```sql
SELECT MONTHS.N AS Monat, COALESCE(RESULT.summe,0) AS summe, RESULT.masch_nr
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) AS MONTHS(N)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT masch_nr, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(gut_pri)/1000) as summe
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll]
    WHERE masch_nr='FIMI3'
    AND satz_art='T'
    AND YEAR(begin_ts)='2021'
    AND MONTH(begin_ts) = MONTHS.N
    GROUP BY masch_nr
) AS RESULT
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table that stores the months of the year and relate to query through the left join

EX:

```
Create table dbo.tMonth (
  nuMonth INT,
  nmMonth nvarchar(20),
  abbMonth nvarchar(3)
)

insert into dbo.tMonth values(1,'January','jan')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(2,'febrary','fev')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(3,'March','mar')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(4,'April','apr')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(5,'May','may')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(6,'June','jun')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(7,'July','jul')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(8,'August','ago')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(9,'September','set')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(10,'October','out')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(11,'November','nov')
insert into dbo.tMonth values(12,'December','dec')


SELECT masch_nr, ISNULL(summe,0) summe,Monat FROM dbo.tMonth m left join (
SELECT masch_nr, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(gut_pri)/1000) as summe, 
MONTH(begin_ts) as Monat
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll]
    WHERE masch_nr='FIMI3'
    AND satz_art='T'
    AND YEAR(begin_ts)='2021'
    GROUP BY masch_nr, MONTH(begin_ts) ) as q 
ON m.nuMonth = q.Monat
```